# Execute a program instead of reading static file as response to php file read

Tags: php, linux

We've got a PHP code that is currently reading a config file to get some definitions and passwords. 
The PHP code is out of my control and I cannot ask for code changes.
As I need the ability to change the config dynamically, I would like to execute a binary (written in go) every time the PHP code is trying to read the config. 
The workflow that I think of will be something like: 
PHP ask to read the file (fopen() for example) -> an executable is running and outputting the generated config -> the PHP code is getting the output as if it was reading a static file.
I'm not much of a Linux guru and I'm having difficulties understanding if it's possible or not and if it does, how to do it.
We're using Debian 9 and running PHP 7.2
Any ideas if it's possible and how to make it work?

Comment: How come you can't change the PHP code?

Comment: It's going to be a very brittle system relying on hacks such as this.

Comment: How often is your config changing that you need to regenerate it every time PHP runs?

Comment: Surely the config won't be different **every** time PHP reads the file (which could be once per HTTP request, if there's no caching)? How often does the config change? Most configs are pretty static...do you have some unusual circumstances? I'd have thought all you need is some way of updating the config file automatically from time to time (you haven't specified what the trigger for changing the config actually is). PHP will then pick up those changes when it next reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

ADyson's comment is quite worthy of consideration. If you insist on executing a program rather than asynchronously updating the file, this can be done: Create a [named pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) with `mkfifo config` and continuously run the program, opening, writing to and closing the *config* in a loop. But you'd have to ensure that no two instances of the PHP code try to read at the same time.